# What Explained Variance is good to proceed with Predictive Soil Mapping?

Tags: dem, regression, modelling, random-forest, soil

I have 1851 soil samples data on pH covering a study area of 7482sq.km in northern Ghana and I am using 52 environmental long-term average variables (Relief, Climate, MODIS Reflectances and derived products) to fit a model in order to explain the variability for pH prediction. So far, all models tested have shown low explained variance and sometimes even gives negative.

How may I improve the Explained Variance below?

See pictures below, the spatial distribution of points.

**Below is the summary of my models explained variance.**

Multiple Linear Regression: 0.03

Step-wise Multiple Linear Regression: 0.04

RandomForest: -7.02

ExtremeGradient Boosting: 0.03

Support Vector Machines with Polynomial Kernel: 0.03

**Additional information about the sample raw data**

1. Avg. distance between two sample points using nearest neighbor analysis: 2551.29m
2. Data source: Student research
3. Sampling method: Grid/Management Zone Hybrid Soil Sampling method. The grid size is 2-4sq.km, management zones are subdivisions within the grid.

**My assessment so far**

1. Removed points falling outside the study area
2. Removed pH value outliers
3. Normality check was ok (please see attached)
4. Variography shows a spatial structure (please see attached)
5. Tried recursive feature elimination to reduce the dimensionality but did not show any improvement
6. Tried reducing dimensionality by removing highly correlated covariates at a threshold of 0.75

I seek insights into any techniques that could help improve the model explained variance.

**ATTACHED IMAGES BELOW**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your variogram is showing that the pH values are spatially independent.
I would say that you need to find better explanatory variables for soil pH. Can you please add a map where you color the points using a gradient color scheme from low pH to high pH.

Comment: Hi @TheSteve0, many thanks for your thoughts regarding the variogram. Kindly see the pH map I just added above.

Comment: It looks like you should try directional variograms and see if you get stronger responses